# JSON Python Google maps get all directions

Tags: python, json, google-maps, parsing

I trying to get directions from A to B using Google maps API, but I'm hitting a stupid error, which I can't fix by myself, your help will be appreciated. So, here is my code

```
import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime
import pprint
import json

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='HIDDEN')
now = datetime.now()
directions_result = gmaps.directions("Sydney Olympic Park, New South Wales 2127, Australia",
                                 "Parramatta, NSW",
                                 mode="transit",
                                 departure_time=now)

for leg in directions_result[0]['legs']:
    startAddress = leg['start_address']
    print "Start Address:", startAddress
    endAddress = leg['end_address']
    print "End Address:", endAddress
    distance=leg['distance']['text']
    print "Distance:",distance
    duration=leg['duration']['text']
    print "Duration:",duration
    for step in leg['steps']:
        html_instructions = step['html_instructions']
        instr= step['distance']['text']
        instrtime=step['duration']['text']
        print html_instructions + " " +instr+ " " + instrtime
        #till here works fine
        for stepp in step['steps']:
            y=step['steps'][0]['html_instructions']# but I would like to get step['steps']['steps']['html_instructions'], but got  'list index must be int not str'
            print y
            #this loop runs 1 time and then gives an error
```

Here is the Output I get:

```
Start Address: Sydney Olympic Park NSW 2127, Australia
End Address: Parramatta NSW 2150, Australia
Distance: 11.1 km
Duration: 36 mins
Walk to Olympic Park Station 0.3 km 4 mins
Head <b>northeast</b> on <b>Dawn Fraser Ave</b> toward <b>Olympic Blvd</b> <-- This is the 1st passage of "for stepp in step['steps']:"
Head <b>northeast</b> on <b>Dawn Fraser Ave</b> toward <b>Olympic Blvd</b>
Train towards Lidcombe 3.4 km 6 mins
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getdirections.py", line 43, in <module>
    for stepp in step['steps']:
KeyError: 'steps'
```

Looks like python looks for the 1st time, find it, print it, and then looks an other time, but doesn't find it and gives this error, But for cycle should exit when condition is not met.

And here is my JSON reply

```
[{u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': -33.8085175, u'lng': 151.0651324},
          u'southwest': {u'lat': -33.8496094, u'lng': 151.0012743}},
u'copyrights': u'Map data \xa92018 Google',
u'legs': [{u'arrival_time': {u'text': u'1:09pm',
                           u'time_zone': u'Australia/Sydney',
                           u'value': 1515463756},
         u'departure_time': {u'text': u'12:32pm',
                             u'time_zone': u'Australia/Sydney',
                             u'value': 1515461520},
         u'distance': {u'text': u'11.9 km', u'value': 11938},
         u'duration': {u'text': u'37 mins', u'value': 2236},
         u'end_address': u'Parramatta NSW 2150, Australia',
         u'end_location': {u'lat': -33.8146729, u'lng': 151.0012743},
         u'start_address': u'Sydney Olympic Park NSW 2127, Australia',
         u'start_location': {u'lat': -33.8484821, u'lng': 151.0651324},
         u'steps': [{u'distance': {u'text': u'0.2 km', u'value': 243},
                     u'duration': {u'text': u'3 mins', u'value': 198},
                     u'end_location': {u'lat': -33.849457,
                                       u'lng': 151.062759},
                     u'html_instructions': u'Walk to Dawn Fraser Ave before Edwin Flack Ave',
                     u'polyline': {u'points': u'~_rmEa|_y[Pn@bBpGz@|CPE'},
                     u'start_location': {u'lat': -33.8484821,
                                         u'lng': 151.0651324},
                     u'steps': [{u'distance': {u'text': u'0.2 km',
                                               u'value': 243},
                                 u'duration': {u'text': u'3 mins',
                                               u'value': 198},
                                 u'end_location': {u'lat': -33.849457,
                                                   u'lng': 151.062759},
                                 u'html_instructions': u'Head <b>southwest</b> on <b>Dawn Fraser Ave</b>',
                                 u'polyline': {u'points': u'~_rmEa|_y[Pn@bBpGz@|CPE'},
                                 u'start_location': {u'lat': -33.8484821,
                                                     u'lng': 151.0651324},
                                 u'travel_mode': u'WALKING'}],
                     u'travel_mode': u'WALKING'},
                    {u'distance': {u'text': u'11.2 km',
                                   u'value': 11179},
                     u'duration': {u'text': u'32 mins',
                                   u'value': 1920},
                     u'end_location': {u'lat': -33.8175958,
                                       u'lng': 151.0045742},
                     u'html_instructions': u'Bus towards Parramatta',
                     u'polyline': {u'points': u'bfrmEgm_y[OF?@l@rB_PjHC@iD|AUDi@Bi@CoAc@aAfDQdAGpAHlBCjADnAN\\`@TdHvCaA`Dq@fAy@fAiAx@qCvAoAdAe@n@{AnD?@k@|ASVBJENOHMIEQIIo@c@cAcAS?KKCYk@q@oAkAk@c@UEGO?Iw@k@AAcC}A{BaA_@KQ@IOyAc@gG}AQ?yAs@aBiA}AyAaAkBCEYi@C?OCKWmE~Dg@u@uAa@A?}@Uq@~DoCi@A?eAWm@zD?@cApEuBjMcCdOeB_@kIyBA?kHmB}AUcFa@}f@}CgJi@oH@_BEsBBe@FOPG\\cBjU?@?@{A~SA@?@{Bb[?@eAzN?BgAzNOtAYzA_A`DA@sAzEiB~E?@Qh@uArFeAxFGtA?BDlFXtPEtEMdDw@hI?D}@xJIhBXlI?Hp@rQ?@^rJ?@\\`LQvCKlBjBNfGvApA\\jBr@tBbAzAXNNxBl@B?tEdA@?x@TnCd@jHYd@Wn@y@h@_@xAc@Jh@Bd@Ez@IVANc@dAgBzD'},
                     u'start_location': {u'lat': -33.849457,
                                         u'lng': 151.062759},
                     u'transit_details': {u'arrival_stop': {u'location': {u'lat': -33.8175958,
                                                                          u'lng': 151.0045742},
                                                            u'name': u'Parramatta Station, Stand B3'},
                                          u'arrival_time': {u'text': u'1:03pm',
                                                            u'time_zone': u'Australia/Sydney',
                                                            u'value': 1515463381},
                                          u'departure_stop': {u'location': {u'lat': -33.849457,
                                                                            u'lng': 151.062759},
                                                              u'name': u'Dawn Fraser Ave before Edwin Flack Ave'},
                                          u'departure_time': {u'text': u'12:35pm',
                                                              u'time_zone': u'Australia/Sydney',
                                                              u'value': 1515461719},
                                          u'headsign': u'Parramatta',
                                          u'line': {u'agencies': [{u'name': u'State Transit Sydney',
                                                                   u'phone': u'011 61 13 15 00',
                                                                   u'url': u'http://transportnsw.info/'}],
                                                    u'color': u'#03a9f4',
                                                    u'name': u'Parramatta to Burwood via Sydney Olympic Park',
                                                    u'short_name': u'525',
                                                    u'text_color': u'#ffffff',
                                                    u'vehicle': {u'icon': u'//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/bus2.png',
                                                                 u'local_icon': u'//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transit/iw2/6/au-sydney-bus.png',
                                                                 u'name': u'Bus',
                                                                 u'type': u'BUS'}},
                                          u'num_stops': 27},
                     u'travel_mode': u'TRANSIT'},
                    {u'distance': {u'text': u'0.5 km', u'value': 516},
                     u'duration': {u'text': u'7 mins', u'value': 395},
                     u'end_location': {u'lat': -33.8146729,
                                       u'lng': 151.0012743},
                     u'html_instructions': u'Walk to Parramatta NSW 2150, Australia',
                     u'polyline': {u'points': u'~~kmEqatx[KIEJMTWh@OZMVMZEPELABARANQFI@E@[@E?A?A?CAAACAEGSN[NMFMDIBK@UBG@IAC?A?G?YDQBC@CBA@A@A@CBKJKFMDOBG@E?E?QACVIf@Kr@[xBSzA'},
                     u'start_location': {u'lat': -33.8175958,
                                         u'lng': 151.0045742},
                     u'steps': [{u'distance': {u'text': u'0.1 km',
                                               u'value': 123},
                                 u'duration': {u'text': u'1 min',
                                               u'value': 84},
                                 u'end_location': {u'lat': -33.8170114,
                                                   u'lng': 151.0034771},
                                 u'html_instructions': u'Head <b>northwest</b> on <b>Liverpool-Parramatta Transitway</b> toward <b>Church St</b>',
                                 u'polyline': {u'points': u'~~kmEqatx[KIEJMTWh@OZMVMZEPELABARAN'},
                                 u'start_location': {u'lat': -33.8175958,
                                                     u'lng': 151.0045742},
                                 u'travel_mode': u'WALKING'},
                                {u'distance': {u'text': u'52 m',
                                               u'value': 52},
                                 u'duration': {u'text': u'1 min',
                                               u'value': 33},
                                 u'end_location': {u'lat': -33.8165694,
                                                   u'lng': 151.0034844},
                                 u'html_instructions': u'Turn <b>right</b> onto <b>Church St</b>',
                                 u'maneuver': u'turn-right',
                                 u'polyline': {u'points': u'h{kmEwzsx[QFI@E@[@E?A?A?CAAACAEG'},
                                 u'start_location': {u'lat': -33.8170114,
                                                     u'lng': 151.0034771},
                                 u'travel_mode': u'WALKING'},
                                {u'distance': {u'text': u'0.2 km',
                                               u'value': 183},
                                 u'duration': {u'text': u'2 mins',
                                               u'value': 134},
                                 u'end_location': {u'lat': -33.8150393,
                                                   u'lng': 151.0029224},
                                 u'html_instructions': u'Turn <b>left</b> to stay on <b>Church St</b>',
                                 u'maneuver': u'turn-left',
                                 u'polyline': {u'points': u'pxkmEwzsx[SN[NMFMDIBK@UBG@IAC?A?G?YDQBC@CBA@A@A@CBKJKFMDOBG@E?E?QA'},
                                 u'start_location': {u'lat': -33.8165694,
                                                     u'lng': 151.0034844},
                                 u'travel_mode': u'WALKING'},
                                {u'distance': {u'text': u'0.2 km',
                                               u'value': 158},
                                 u'duration': {u'text': u'2 mins',
                                               u'value': 144},
                                 u'end_location': {u'lat': -33.8146729,
                                                   u'lng': 151.0012743},
                                 u'html_instructions': u'Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>Macquarie St</b>',
                                 u'maneuver': u'turn-left',
                                 u'polyline': {u'points': u'~nkmEgwsx[CVIf@Kr@[xBSzA'},
                                 u'start_location': {u'lat': -33.8150393,
                                                     u'lng': 151.0029224},
                                 u'travel_mode': u'WALKING'}],
                     u'travel_mode': u'WALKING'}],
         u'traffic_speed_entry': [],
         u'via_waypoint': []}],
u'overview_polyline': {u'points': u'~_rmEa|_y[tB`Iz@|CPEOHl@rB_PjHC@iD|AUDi@Bi@CoAc@aAfDQdAGpAHlBCjADnAN\\fIlDaA`Dq@fAy@fAiAx@qCvAoAdAe@n@{AnD?@k@|ASVBJENOHMIEQIIo@c@cAcAS?KKCYk@q@{BoBUEGO?Iw@k@AAcC}A{BaA_@KQ@IOyAc@gG}AQ?yAs@aBiA}AyAaAkB]o@SCKWmE~Dg@u@uAa@A?}@Uq@~DqCi@eAWm@|DcApEuBjMcCdOqLyCmHmB}AUcFa@}f@}CgJi@oH@_BEsBBe@FOPG\\cBlU{A`T}Bf[eA`OgAzNOtAYzA_A`DA@sAzEiB~EQj@uArFeAxFGxADlFXtPEtEMdDw@nI}@xJIhBXvIpAj]\\`LQvCKlBjBNfGvApA\\jBr@tBbAzAXNNxBl@xEdAz@TnCd@jHYd@Wn@y@h@_@xAc@Jh@Bd@Ez@IVANc@dAgBzDKIS`@cAxBK^CVANQFOBe@@OMo@^[Ls@JWAs@NIHWR]HM@WAu@lFSzA'},
u'summary': u'',
u'warnings': [u'Walking directions are in beta.    Use caution \u2013 This route may be missing sidewalks or pedestrian paths.'],
u'waypoint_order': []}]
```

Once again, I need to extract all the directions from the JSON, some of them are indented [legs][steps][steps], I'm able to get all [legs][steps] but have problems parsing [legs][steps][steps]
I'm fighting with this the 2nd day, and don't know where to look. All the previous questions on stackoverflow does not reply to this issue, please don't mark as duplicate (I've already read all the related posts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if 'steps' is in your dict before accessing it.

```
 ...
 #till here works fine
 if 'steps' in step:
     for stepp in step['steps']:
         y=stepp['html_instructions']
         print y
```

Does this do what you want?

Comment: Man, you're the best! Thanks
I've tried this before if step['steps'] : , but now I see the error

Comment: glad I could help :)